# Is there anyway I can add authentication to a QR Code which I generated using python?

Tags: python, authentication, qr-code

```
import qrcode
qr=qrcode.make("magic")
qr.save("test.png")
```

This is my 2 line code to generate a QRcode using the qrcode library in python. Is there any way I can add authentication. To be more precise the user should be asked for a password when he scans the qrcode and he/she should be given access if the password is correct.

the first line is used to import the qrcode python library into the script we are writing. The second line is the object which holds the data inside the qrcode. Here the data I have saved is just a string.."magic". the 3rd line saves the qr into a image which can be scanned by devices.Here giving access to means..giving access to the data inside qr.. here the data inside the qr is the string .."magic"

Comment: Given access to *what*, exactly?  All of this seems to be talking about features of the program that scans the code, not the one that creates it.

Comment: apparently the code is to create a qrcode. the first line is used to import the qrcode python library into the script we are writing. The second line is the object which holds the data inside the qrcode. Here the data I have saved is just a string.."magic". the 3rd line saves the qr into a image which can be scanned by devices.Here giving access to means..giving access to the data inside qr.. here the data inside the qr is the string .."magic"

Comment: You can put a URL into the code and protect the access to the URL. But that is not a programming topic.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. That might help